# Silverlight Prism Event Aggregator not reliable

Tags: silverlight, prism

I'm experiencing some reliability issues with Prism/Silverlight. I got couple of modules one publishing events and other subscribing.

Every time when I run the application from VS on debug mode by pressing "F5", the events are published and subscribed as expected. However, when I run the application from visual studio by pressing "Ctrl+F5", then the event publication/subscription is matter of luck. Sometime its working, sometimes its not working.

Anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: What version of the Prism library are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause I've seen for this issue is that the subscriber is being GCed. This [blog post](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2009/05/prism-event-aggregator-subscription.html) gives an explanation of why it could happen and provides a way to solve it.

Other than that, I can think of no other cause for this to happen.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you subscribe to events before their are published. Make sure that all your publishers are initialized first;